# MDX query does not return any values, which it should - possibly due to the where clause

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, where-clause

I'm trying to create a data set in SSRS with the following MDX Query:

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Quantity],[Measures].[Total Price],
[Measures]Margin],[Measures].[Profit Margin] } on columns,
NON EMPTY {([Dim Product2].[Product Group], [Dim Product2].[Summary],
[Dim Time].[Open Hour Bucket].allmembers)} on rows
from [theyseemecubin]
where {([Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[1046],[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].&[2014-11-20])}
```

where I want to summarize some store's Daily sales, for a specific date. When I only had:

```
where [Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[1046]
```

in the where clause, the Query returned the correct data. But when I attempted to insert the `Date` as well, then the result set becomes nothing, although I have checked in the cube that there should have been 14 units sold that day.

What am I doing wrong? Have I misinterpreted how to use the SQL equivallence `Where StoreKey = 1046 AND Date=2014-11-20` in MDX?

Comment: Try to move [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].Members to the row section in order to see all non-empty dates. Does it return the 2014-11-20 member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks ok as it is:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Quantity]
     ,[Measures].[Total Price]
     ,[Measures].[Margin]
     ,[Measures].[Profit Margin]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      (
        [Dim Product2].[Product Group]
       ,[Dim Product2].[Summary]
       ,[Dim Time].[Open Hour Bucket].ALLMEMBERS
      )
    } ON ROWS
FROM [theyseemecubin]
WHERE 
  {
    (
      [Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[1046]
     ,[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].&[2014-11-20]
    )
  };
```

You don't need the curly braces as just the tuple will be sufficient:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Quantity]
     ,[Measures].[Total Price]
     ,[Measures].[Margin]
     ,[Measures].[Profit Margin]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      (
        [Dim Product2].[Product Group]
       ,[Dim Product2].[Summary]
       ,[Dim Time].[Open Hour Bucket].ALLMEMBERS
      )
    } ON ROWS
FROM [theyseemecubin]
WHERE 
    (
      [Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[1046]
     ,[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].&[2014-11-20]
    );
```

A tuple is a logical `AND` so yes it is equivalent to the sql. If you want to do a logical `OR` you need to change things a little and make use of a set.

Maybe one thing to check - is this defintiely the full name of the member? `[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].&[2014-11-20]` ... most mdx tools (SSMS and MDXstudio) you should be able to just drag and drop the member into the query pane to see the full name.

Comment: @whyteq        Reading your code is like poetry. I'll ensure to format it like that in the future - looks very tidy. I adjusted my code to yours, and I could then solve my issue. It was due to the tuple misinterpretation, so thanks again!

Comment: @Cenderze many people would say nothing and take the praise - but the pretty code formatting is down to me pressing the button "Format Code" in the free application `MdxStudio` ! Definitely makes things clearer.